# how to fix eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i'm practicing how Indonesian Hate Speech Classification from https://github.com/GigasTaufan/Indonesian-Hate-Speech-Classification
but in slang word Removal, i want change source request with another source,
this code from the link

```
import requests
slang_word = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/louisowen6/NLP_bahasa_resources/master/combined_slang_words.txt').text
dict_slang = eval(slang_word)
```

and i want change code line requests to

```
slang_word = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/okkyibrohim/id-multi-label-hate-speech-and-abusive-language-detection/master/new_kamusalay.csv').csv
dict_slang = eval(slang_word)
```

but i got error
like this

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-55ee3a28f142> in <module>()
      1 slang_word = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/okkyibrohim/id-multi-label-hate-speech-and-abusive-language-detection/master/new_kamusalay.csv')
----> 2 dict_slang = eval(slang_word)

TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

What'd be a good way to do this then? Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to get with `eval(csv)`?

Comment: Look at what `requests.get` returns. You get a response object, and you _can_ get a string out of it, but it's not a string _at first_.

Comment: BTW, `eval`ing content you got off the internet is not a great thing to be doing from a security perspective (it's a bit better if you pin it to an audited commitish and trust github). Someone who owns one of these gists could change it to something that, say, drops a rootkit.

Comment: just do what the example that works does, add the .text to the end of you requests line so you get a str object and not a requests response object

Comment: (that said, LeiYang makes an important point -- if the content _really is_ a CSV, `eval` isn't going to do anything useful with it).

Comment: my teacher said to use this reference https://raw.githubusercontent.com/okkyibrohim/id-multi-label-hate-speech-and-abusive-language-detection/master/new_kamusalay.csv for the slang word removal. and i dont really understand how to fix it. when i use  slang_word = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/okkyibrohim/id-multi-label-hate-speech-and-abusive-language-detection/master/new_kamusalay.csv').csv 
the error change to 'Response' object has no attribute 'csv'

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if eval can't read content a CSV, can you sir 
recommend what code to use for me ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @MhdMustafaWahid, it's `.text`, not `.csv` to get the text from the response. (There's no reason for the `requests` library to know or care what the text represents -- if it's a CSV or anything else; it's a different component's job -- in this case the `csv` library's -- to know how to parse it)